# Increasing height of other row when one row height is increased in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using table to display content. There are 3 rows in table. In each row(with 2 td), there can be multiple line content. Now, it works perfectly fine in Mozila, chrome when content is spread in more than 1 line (it only increases height of that particular row) but in IE8,IE9, it also increases the height of the other tr.
Here is my code for table.

```
<table id="tbl_polls" style="border:none; width:100%">                                                                     
  <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2" class="poll-q">
              POLL QUESTION    
         </td>               
      </tr>                 
       <tr>
            <td style="width:3%;float:left">                                    
                <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="108" name="answer">&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td style="width:97%;float:left" >                                
                ANS 1: Carmont wins by retire
            </td>
      </tr>             
      <tr>
          <td style="width:3%;float:left" >                                 
            <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="109" name="answer">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td style="width:97%;float:left" >                                
            ANS 2: Carmont wins by decision                                
          </td>
     </tr>              
     <tr>
          <td style="width:3%;float:left" >                                 
            <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="110" name="answer">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td style="width:97%;float:left" >                                
            ANS 3: someone wins but i'm just not sure if i can make a specific decision as to what i think will happen exactly,this is longest answer and its spreads                   
          </td>
     </tr>              
    </tbody>
```

EDIT:
I have uploaded it on.
http://designs.digitaldreamstech.com/boldtiger/polls/

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with this,

```
<table id="tbl_polls" style="border:none; width:100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tr>
    <td valign="center" colspan="2">
        POLL QUESTION    
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>                                    
        <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="108" name="answer">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>                                
        ANS 1: Carmont wins by retire
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>                                 
        <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="109" name="answer">&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td >                                
        ANS 2: Carmont wins by decision                                
      </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>                                 
        <input type="radio" style="margin: 2px 0 0 2px; display:inline-block" value="110" name="answer">&nbsp;
      </td>
      <td>                                
        ANS 3: someone wins but i'm just not sure if i can make a specific decision as to what i think will happen exactly,this is longest answer and its spreads                   
      </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Now please check the page in all browsers. It was working perfect.

Comment: no, it is not working. It is showing same amount of height in all row because of 3rd row contains 2 lines.

Comment: I'm +1'ing this answer, because if you replaced the code with his it would have been fine. Im quite sure you didn't made all your code look like this here.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you are doing very odd things with tables, floating table cells is usually not your best idea and probably breaks things in atleast IE and probably also other browsers. And tables are usually not the best way to design a form.

What i suggest is the following structure for your table:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="radio" value="109" name="answer" />
            <label for="input_1">ANS 2: Caromt wins by decision</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
div.row {
    clear: both;
}
label {
    float: left;
}
input {
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
}
```

You can find more ways to properly structure a form here: http://www.gethifi.com/blog/html-forms-the-right-ways

Comment: I had tried it with by removing float:left also and it was still not working.

Comment: Then i see no obvious reason for the behaviour in IE. Other tr's should not increase height when one changes. Is there any other CSS loaded?

Comment: Now that i think of it. I think the only way the behaviour you mentioned could happen is when a fixed height is set on the table..

Comment: In that case im almost positive there has to be some other CSS interfering. IE7/8 simply does not increase the height of a tr when another tr's height grows. Some javascript could also set those styles. So do use your browsers inspect element functionality to see what styles are active when the rows height is increased.

Comment: I am not able to find any script that is interfering. Please check     http://designs.digitaldreamstech.com/boldtiger/polls/        (See poll question in IE,chore and firefox).

Comment: Yikes man. Not to insult, but your code is a mess. First of all i still see the float: lefts on td's. Also you set both `width="97%"` aswell as `style: width 97%` on your td, why?..

Comment: And to make things worse.. your problem is fixed if you take way all the float: lefts like I said before. You need to take it off both td's. Not just one. Remove the floats and everything is find.. You wasted my time :(

Comment: I had removed float:left from both tds but still it shows the same error.Thanks for your time but still it is not working. I am deleting this question now as I am not able to find right answer.

Comment: You did get the right answer, you are just not doing the correct implementation. I've removed the floats from your source and everything was fine in IE.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I had re-uploaded the code with the removal of float:left from all tables. I am now using text-align:left. It is still not working.I had removed the text-align:left also and still not working.